# Left quotation mark not showing in GFS Didot Classic

Tags: fonts, luatex

I don't get why the left quotation mark doesn't show here

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{GFSDidot_Classic.otf}

\begin{document}

`ἄνθρωπος'

\end{document}
```

I've checked that U+2018 is present in the [font](http://greekfontsociety-gfs.gr/_assets/fonts/GFS_Didot_Classic.zip).
[image]

Comment: The problem is imho that U÷60 (the input) is not in the font and so luatex won't  do the substitution with U÷2018.

Comment: I get [this picture (click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A0QH.png) with the left quote (XeLaTeX). The quote is missing with LuaLaTeX. Use `‘` instead of the back quote.

Comment: @egreg, I prefer to use `.  I'll try to put something into U+60.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to write up an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is imho that U÷60 (the input) is not in the font and so luatex won't do the substitution with U÷2018.

Comment: intersting +1 +1